# `GLIBC_2.34' not found

Tags: linux, glibc

I'm trying to use the Heroku command line on Ubuntu, but coming up with an error, which I don't think is related to Heroku specifically.

When I run `heroku login` I get

```
/snap/heroku/current/bin/node: /snap/core/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0)
```

I get a similar error when I try to run `gitkraken`, so I assume it's not related to heroku.

`libc6` is installed already.

```
libc6 is already the newest version (2.36-0ubuntu4).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 15 not to upgrade.
```

Looking at `apt policy libc6`

```
libc6:
  Installed: 2.36-0ubuntu4
  Candidate: 2.36-0ubuntu4
  Version table:
 *** 2.36-0ubuntu4 500
        500 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

I tried upgrading my Linux version so it's now

```
Linux 5.19.0-46-generic x86_64
```

And I've checked all my bashrc, profile and other files to see if something is being set, but it's not.
What can I do next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Snap installs are no longer supported. Use one of these install methods.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli

Answer (score 1):

> I tried upgrading my Linux version so it's now

You are barking up the wrong tree -- there is *nothing* wrong with your Linux installation.

Your problem comes from SNAP mixing up system libraries (`libgtk3-nocsd.so.0` here) with a "custom" `libc.so.6` (the `/snap/core/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6` here).

You should be able to just move `/snap/core/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` out of the way, or at least remove `libc.so.6`, `libpthread.so.0`, `libm.so.6`, and other parts of GLIBC from it and run the binary.

Comment: I didn't try this, as the other solution was simpler! 
I read somewhere that I needed to upgrade the OS, as a simplified way to upgrade libc6, otherwise things would be out of sync.

Comment: impossible - error: "Filesystem is readonly"